# PyFacebook with Pylons

Tags: python, facebook, pylons, pyfacebook

I'd like to implement PyFacebook in my Python + Pylons application.  Where should I include the package?  What's the cleanest way to import it?  What directory should I put the files in?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most of your libraries are on your pythonpath, which mostly is lib/site-packages. You should just install those and most installers will make sure they're on your python-path. Then you should be able to import them normally.